# Configure Many to Many relationship

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

For this I have 3 models: Hospitals, AspNetUsers, UserHospitals.

this is the UserHospitals model:

```
public class UserHospital
{
    [Key]
    public int UserHospitalID { get; set; }

    public int HospitalID { get; set; }
    public Hospital Hospitals { get; set; }

    public string Id { get; set; }
    public ApplicationUser Users { get; set; }
}
```

With it I can add User ID and Hospital ID to this table.

Now, I need to check which hospitals user's connected.

On my controller that return an hospital list i need to return only Hospitals that user's have a connection.

This return all hospitals, how can I filter it to show only if user have a connection with hospital on UserHospitals?

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(db.Hospitals.ToList());
    }
```

I don't want to add a new viewmodel that join models or whatever

==  EDIT  ==

Hospital Model

```
public class Hospital
{
    [Key]
    public int HospitalID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<HospitalSpeciality> HospitalSpecialities { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<UserHospital> UserHospitals { get; set; }
}
```

[image]

Comment: How you  get connection of user to a hospital ? If its UserHosipital Id its is `db.Hosipitals.where(h=>h.UserHosipitalId==expectedId)`

Comment: Hospital -> UserHospital -> User, I don't have a direct connection to user's by Hospital model. You can see it on my edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 public ActionResult Index()
 {
    var result =db.Hospitals.Include("UserHospitals").where(x=> x.UserHospitals.Any(x=>x.Id== userId)).ToList();
    return View(result);
 }
```

Comment: If you can, take a look to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37053194/block-access-by-query-result) plz: