# block access by query result

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have Hospitals and Medical Specialities.

My Medical Specialities page return data by hospital ID in this way:

localhost/MedicalSpecialities/1, 1 is the HospitalID. if I change manually the link I can access any hospital info.

I have users associated to hospitals in this way:
[image]

I need to query the Hospital ID's that user have associated AND check if the current HospitalID is on the list.

This return all hospitals that user have connected:

```
        var userID = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        var result = db.Hospitals.Include("UserHospitals")
                              .Where(x => x.UserHospitals
                              .Any(u => u.Id == userID))
                              .ToList();
```

Comment: what is the difference between connected and associated ?

Comment: There's no difference

Comment: Your linq query should give you the hospitals associated with the specific user id. What are you missing ?

Comment: My query can result more than 1 row. I don't know how to do my condition `if query hospital ID == ID` in this scenario

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can basically update the  condition in your `Any()` method to include a check against the HospitalId column.

```
var hospitalId =5;
var result = db.Hospitals
               .Include(y=>y.UserHospitals)
               .Where(x => x.UserHospitals.Any(u => u.Id == userID 
                                                 && u.HospitalID==hospitalId ))
               .ToList();
```

If you are expecting only a single hospital for this condition, you may also consider using `FirstOrDefault()` method.

```
var singleHospital = db.Hospitals
                       .Include(y=>y.UserHospitals)
                       .Where(x => x.UserHospitals.Any(u => u.Id == userID 
                                                         && u.HospitalID==hospitalId ))
                       .FirstOrDefault();
if(singleHospital!=null)
{
     //Safely use it.
}
```

Comment: Sry but on the "Any" i get "Operator && cannot be applied to operands type bool or int"

Comment: Sorry fixed now( two `==` )

Comment: Anyway I thing that it does not solve my problem. I will show you my controller [here.](https://i.gyazo.com/617d528b7f8f09a8610d9e878c57425f.png) I just want to do an IF that check if user and hospital are connected, if false, then he get an error page, if true, it does the main query and return all data

Comment: why it does not solve your problem ? your query should give you the filtered item for that specific hospital and user.

Comment: I did [this](https://i.gyazo.com/df369c9daef1f0149f64ea5f60e39a39.png) and I still can change the id on the link and access the page

Comment: You are doing a null check on the result of `ToList` call. It will be always true( empty list, but not null). You should use the `FirstOrDefault` instead.

Comment: That's it! Thanks you!