# LINQ query to filter page results

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

Tables/Models I have: `Users`, `Hospitals`, `UserHospitals`, `UserAcesses` and `UserAcessesViewModel`.

I have a page that shows all user acesses.

I send the hospital ID by link /UserAcess/1

I need to query if user have a connection to the Hospital ID on table `UserHospitals` and if it's true, show all acesses from users that are connected to the same Hospital ID.

That's what I have and my query is incorrect:

```
    public ActionResult Index(int? id, string searchString, string sortOrder, string SelectedUserId)
    {
        if(!User.IsInRole("Admin"))
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return View("Error");

            }
            else if (!db.Hospitals.Any(o => o.HospitalID == id))
            {
                return View("Error");
            }

            var model = new UserAccessViewModel();
            var userAccesses = db.UserAccesses.Include(u => u.User);

            ViewBag.IDSortParm = sortOrder == "ID_asc" ? "ID_desc" : "ID_asc";
            ViewBag.EmailSortParm = sortOrder == "Email_asc" ? "Email_desc" : "Email_asc";
            ViewBag.DateSortParm = sortOrder == "Date" ? "date_desc" : "Date";
            ViewBag.NameSortParm = sortOrder == "Name_asc" ? "Name_desc" : "Name_asc";

            var userID = User.Identity.GetUserId();
            var result = db.Hospitals.Include("UserHospitals")
                              .Where(x => x.UserHospitals
                              .Any(u => u.Id == userID && u.HospitalID == id))
                              .FirstOrDefault();

            if (result != null)
            {
                userAccesses = db.UserAccesses.Include(u => u.User).Include("UserHospitals").Where(w => w.User.any())));
            }
            else
            {
                return View("Error");
            }
        }
```

My models:

Hospital

```
public class Hospital
{
    [Key]
    public int HospitalID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<HospitalSpeciality> HospitalSpecialities { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<UserHospital> UserHospitals { get; set; }
}
```

UserHospital

```
public class UserHospital
{
    [Key]
    public int UserHospitalID { get; set; }

    public int HospitalID { get; set; }
    public Hospital Hospitals { get; set; }

    public string Id { get; set; }
    public ApplicationUser Users { get; set; }
}
```

UserAcesses

```
public class UserAccess
{
    [Key]
    public int UserAcessID { get; set; }
    public DateTime Access { get; set; }



    public string UserID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("UserID")]

    public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
}
```

UserAcessViewModel

```
public class UserAccessViewModel
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<UserAccess> UserAccesses { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Selecionar Utilizador")]
    public string SelectedUserId { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> UserNamesList;
}
```

There's my [table's connection](https://i.gyazo.com/6a054b9e9603ee58407dfbcd37edfd9c.png)

If you need more information abount my Hospital - UserHospital - User, it's [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37052129/configure-many-to-many-relationship)

Answer (score 0):

Please do some refinement if required in selecting the columns.

```
List<UserHospitals> _userHospitals=  (from p in obj.UserHospitals 
where (p.HospitalID == _hospitalId || p.IsStatus==1)
.GroupBy(p => p.HospitalID)
select new {}.ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I did not understood it

Comment: you want all the access connected to hospital id.Am i right ?.

Comment: I want all accesses from users that have their ID connected to the current Hospital ID on UserHospitals. [This is the result of your code](https://i.gyazo.com/663b08c36fa1dd3c740577153b07a6be.png)

Comment: You have to create a View model class of "UserHospitals" that consists of all the required columns in the output,what my query does when you assign some hospital id it feteches all the user access if status is true corresponding to that hospital.that's it..

Comment: Isn't possible do that without more models, just with my actual models?

Comment: @DenisV we use view models in that case when we need less joins and want to select columns from single model as required.

Comment: When I create a view model, it creates the table on Database, is possible to create a view model without it creating the table?

Comment: It isn't working... [See here](https://i.gyazo.com/8d9adb10be9ca197ebfb89dd15b5500b.png) @user1474602

Comment: You can define a million Models and not have them connected to the database. Providing there are no relational links to the model from your domain model it will be ignored :)

Comment: I would suggest adding a relational property to UserAccess for the Hospital, that might make life easier.